# Setting the label of a paper-icon-button

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

Previous to the current paper-element release 0.6.., I was able to do the following

```dart
  <paper-icon-button
    id='add-btn'
    class='margin-l-t-r-2'
    label='LANGUAGE'
    icon='menu'
    on-click='{{toggle}}'>
  </paper-icon-button>
```

and the button would contain both the icon and the label.
Now the label is not displayed, only the icon on the button. Any help is appreciated in how can I get both label and icon on the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, this has been different in PolymerJS for a while now. They're starting to do things as child elements more often, like this:

```dart
<paper-button>
  <core-icon icon="favorite"></core-icon>
  label goes here
</paper-button>
```

Docs here: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-button

Note that the `<paper-icon-button>` was probably always intended to be used just for icons. If you want an icon and a label, `<paper-button>` is the way to go, as per my example.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously some changes have been made with the paper-icon-button.

Comment: Documentation is now at https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-icon-button